# SQL scripts inside /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d directory are not executed

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle12c

I have installed Oracle 12c in docker container based on oraclelinux:7.1 image (Docker version 1.12.5). There is a slight issue though. When running the container none of my scripts in directory /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d gets executed (they create DB user, execute grants, set up schema, etc.). What might be the issue here?

/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d and all SQL files inside it have permissions set to 777. I can login to the DB using default system user.

Below you'll find Dockerfile copying SQL scripts:

```
FROM oracle-12c:latest

USER oracle
ENV ORACLE_SID ORCL
ENV ORACLE_HOME /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1/db_1
ENV PATH $PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
USER root

RUN echo $PATH
COPY init-scripts/* /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

EXPOSE 1521
```

The log from my container:

```
2017-01-13T15:43:09.158097846Z 
**************************
**** Starting up...   ****
**************************
2017-01-13T15:43:09.158142165Z 
/home/oracle/.bashrc: line 12: /usr/sbin/groupadd: Permission denied
2017-01-13T15:43:09.308941164Z 
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 13-JAN-2017 15:43:09
2017-01-13T15:43:09.308978154Z 
Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
2017-01-13T15:43:09.308987178Z 
Starting /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1/db_1/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...
2017-01-13T15:43:09.314168904Z 
TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Log messages written to /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/5657f8f40e69/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=5657f8f40e69)(PORT=1521)))
2017-01-13T15:43:15.939107815Z 
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                13-JAN-2017 15:43:09
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 6 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/5657f8f40e69/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=5657f8f40e69)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
/home/oracle/.bashrc: line 12: /usr/sbin/groupadd: Permission denied
Processing Database instance "ORCL": log file /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1/db_1/startup.log
/home/oracle/.bashrc: line 12: /usr/sbin/groupadd: Permission denied
2017-01-13T15:43:42.583817187Z 
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 13-JAN-2017 15:43:42
2017-01-13T15:43:42.583862324Z 
Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
2017-01-13T15:43:42.583872256Z 
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                13-JAN-2017 15:43:09
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 33 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/5657f8f40e69/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=5657f8f40e69)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "ORCL" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCL", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
2017-01-13T15:43:42.609310535Z 
**************************
**** Startup finished ****
**************************
2017-01-13T15:43:42.609351046Z
```

Comment: I might be missing something obvious here, but: why should your scripts in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` be executed in the first place / which process do you expect to execute them? Docker? The Oracle DB startup script? Your login shell?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: Isn't this the default behavior? Container with Oracle 11g executed these scripts. Image with Oracle 12c is based on the Dockerfile for Oracle 11g image. I've probably missed something, but I have no idea what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about that part of the docker-entrypoint.sh:

```bash
for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
    case "$f" in
        *.sh)     echo "[IMPORT] $0: running $f"; . "$f" ;;
        *.sql)    echo "[IMPORT] $0: running $f"; echo "exit" | su oracle -c "NLS_LANG=.$CHARACTER_SET /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/xe/bin/sqlplus -S / as sysdba @$f"; echo ;;
        *)        echo "[IMPORT] $0: ignoring $f" ;;
    esac
    echo
done
```

I've been dealing with the same issue for MySQL and PostgreSQL dockers and the workaround I found so far is to loop through an absolute path. Until we find the actual explanation, which might be very simple, here is what you can do:

1. In the Dockerfile, do something like:

   ```
   # docker-entrypoint.sh
   COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
   RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

   # Database scripts
   COPY init-scripts/ /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
   RUN chmod -R +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
   ```
2. Then, in docker-entrypoint.sh, change

```bash
    for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
to

    for f in /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
```

Then build and run the image. It should have run your scripts.
Hope that helps.